# Why does powershell not support add-partitionaccesspath and set-partition commands

Tags: powershell, storage

The `add-partitionaccesspath` and `set-partition` command is not supported as shown below.

```sh
> add-partitionaccesspath -disknumber 2 -partitionnumber 0 -accesspath g:
add-partitionaccesspath : Not Supported

> set-partition -disknumber 2 -partitionnumber 0 -newdriveletter i
set-partition : Not Supported
```

But I can get information about `add-partitionaccesspath` and `set-partition` commands using get-help command.

```sh
> get-help add-partitionaccesspath
NAME
    Add-PartitionAccessPath

> get-help set-partition
NAME
    Set-Partition
```

I would like some help as to why the `add-partitionaccesspath` and `set-partition` commands are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The `Add-PartitionAccessPath` and `Set-Partition` commands can be used when the drive has an **NTFS** file system. You are probably using an external memory to run these commands and the file system is **FAT32**; I assumed because the drive letter specified with the `-accesspath` flag is `g:`. The `Add-PartitionAccessPath` command's reference document states the supported file system. <sub>1</sub>

---

###### Footnotes

<sub>**1.** Mounted folders are supported only on NTFS-formatted partitions.</sub>

---

###### References

- [Add-PartitionAccessPath - Notes Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/add-partitionaccesspath?view=windowsserver2022-ps#notes)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error using `Add-PartitionAccessPath` because I tried to create an access path to an **offline disk**. The disk was offline, because I had mounted two differencing `.avhdx` (snapshot) files that were **linked to the same base** `.vhdx` file.

Mounting the first `.avhdx` file created an *online* disk, but mounting the second one created an *offline* disk. Apparently two `.avhdx` files, that are linked to the same base file, can't be online at the same time, even if you mount them both with `-ReadOnly` flag.

### Repro

This assumes that both `.avhdx` files are linked to the same base `.vhdx` file.

```sh
$vhd1 = Mount-VHD 'C:\…\Disk1.avhdx' -ReadOnly -NoDriveLetter -Passthru
$vhd2 = Mount-VHD 'C:\…\Disk2.avhdx' -ReadOnly -NoDriveLetter -Passthru

# List the online status of the mounted disks
$vhd1, $vhd2 | Get-Disk | Select Number, OperationalStatus

# Try to create access paths for both disks
$vhd1 | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Where Type -eq Basic | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath (New-Item c:\Access1 -ItemType Directory -Force)
$vhd2 | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Where Type -eq Basic | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath (New-Item c:\Access2 -ItemType Directory -Force)
```

**Output:**

```text
Number OperationalStatus
------ -----------------
     3 Online
     4 Offline

Add-PartitionAccessPath : Not Supported
At Line:1 Char:59
+ ... ere Type -eq Basic | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath (New-Item c:\Access2 ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_Partition) [Add-PartitionAccessPath], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 1,Add-PartitionAccessPath
```

### Solution

Dismount the 1st `.avhdx` file before mounting the 2nd `.avhdx` file:

```sh
# Mount the first VHD
$vhd1 = Mount-VHD 'C:\…\Disk1.avhdx' -ReadOnly -NoDriveLetter -Passthru

# Create access path for partition of first disk
$partition1 = $vhd1 | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Where Type -eq Basic
$partition1 | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath (New-Item c:\Access1 -ItemType Directory -Force)

# Work with the files of the VHD through the access path
Get-ChildItem c:\Access1

# Remove partition access path
$partition1 | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath c:\Access1

# Dismount
$vhd1 | Dismount-VHD

# Mount the second VHD
$vhd2 = Mount-VHD 'C:\…\Disk2.avhdx' -ReadOnly -NoDriveLetter -Passthru

# Repeat above steps for the 2nd disk…
```

---

Alternatively you could try to manage the online status of the disks using `Set-Disk -IsOffline`, without dismounting. It still doesn't allow you to set both disks online though, you have two switch one to *offline* status first.

I wouldn't recommend this solution, because I think dismounting is a cleaner way, but here it is for completeness:

```sh
# Assuming both disks are already mounted, we have finished working
# with $vhd1 and now want to use $vhd2

# Force disk1 to offline
$vhd1 | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsOffline $true

# Force disk2 to online
$vhd2 | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsOffline $false

# Should succeed now
$vhd2 | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Where Type -eq Basic | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath (New-Item c:\Access2 -ItemType Directory -Force)
```